# MySQL Workbench, Error 3780 al hacer Forward Engineer

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Utilizo Forward Engineer y el resultado es este.

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema CarolinaAngeles
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema CarolinaAngeles
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `CarolinaAngeles` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `CarolinaAngeles` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `CarolinaAngeles`.`ACCOUNT`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CarolinaAngeles`.`ACCOUNT` (
  `idACCOUNT` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `alias` VARCHAR(40) NULL,
  `mail` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idACCOUNT`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `mail_UNIQUE` (`mail` ASC) VISIBLE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `CarolinaAngeles`.`PERSON`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CarolinaAngeles`.`PERSON` (
  `idPERSON` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `banner` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  `photo` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  `fullName` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `professionalProfile` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  `aboutMe` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  `idACCOUNT` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPERSON`),
  INDEX `fk_PAGE_ACCOUNT_idx` (`idACCOUNT` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PAGE_ACCOUNT`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idACCOUNT`)
    REFERENCES `CarolinaAngeles`.`ACCOUNT` (`idACCOUNT`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `CarolinaAngeles`.`EXPERIENCE`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CarolinaAngeles`.`EXPERIENCE` (
  `idEXPERIENCE` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `job` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `company` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  `startDate` DATE NOT NULL,
  `endDate` DATE NULL,
  `description` TEXT NOT NULL,
  `idPERSON` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idEXPERIENCE`),
  INDEX `fk_EXPERIENCE_PAGE1_idx` (`idPERSON` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_EXPERIENCE_PAGE1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idPERSON`)
    REFERENCES `CarolinaAngeles`.`PERSON` (`idPERSON`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `CarolinaAngeles`.`EDUCATION`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CarolinaAngeles`.`EDUCATION` (
  `idEDUCATION` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `position` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `institution` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `startDate` DATE NOT NULL,
  `endDate` DATE NULL,
  `progress` INT NULL,
  `idPERSON` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idEDUCATION`),
  INDEX `fk_EDUCATION_PAGE1_idx` (`idPERSON` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_EDUCATION_PAGE1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idPERSON`)
    REFERENCES `CarolinaAngeles`.`PERSON` (`idPERSON`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `CarolinaAngeles`.`PROJECT`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CarolinaAngeles`.`PROJECT` (
  `idPROJECT` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `description` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  `image` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `idPERSON` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPROJECT`),
  INDEX `fk_PROJECT_PAGE1_idx` (`idPERSON` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_PROJECT_PAGE1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idPERSON`)
    REFERENCES `CarolinaAngeles`.`PERSON` (`idPERSON`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `CarolinaAngeles`.`LEVEL`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CarolinaAngeles`.`LEVEL` (
  `idLEVEL` INT NOT NULL,
  `level` VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idLEVEL`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `CarolinaAngeles`.`SKILL`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CarolinaAngeles`.`SKILL` (
  `idSKILL` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  `isHard` TINYINT NOT NULL,
  `svg` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
  `idPERSON` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `idLEVEL` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idSKILL`),
  INDEX `fk_SKILL_PAGE1_idx` (`idPERSON` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_SKILL_LEVEL1_idx` (`idLEVEL` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_SKILL_PAGE1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idPERSON`)
    REFERENCES `CarolinaAngeles`.`PERSON` (`idPERSON`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_SKILL_LEVEL1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idLEVEL`)
    REFERENCES `CarolinaAngeles`.`LEVEL` (`idLEVEL`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `CarolinaAngeles`.`PLATFORM`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CarolinaAngeles`.`PLATFORM` (
  `idPLATFORM` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `svg` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idPLATFORM`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `CarolinaAngeles`.`SOCIAL_MEDIA`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CarolinaAngeles`.`SOCIAL_MEDIA` (
  `idSOCIAL_MEDIA` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `url` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `idPERSON` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `idPLATFORM` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idSOCIAL_MEDIA`),
  INDEX `fk_SOCIAL_MEDIA_PAGE1_idx` (`idPERSON` ASC) VISIBLE,
  INDEX `fk_SOCIAL_MEDIA_PLATFORM1_idx` (`idPLATFORM` ASC) VISIBLE,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_SOCIAL_MEDIA_PAGE1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idPERSON`)
    REFERENCES `CarolinaAngeles`.`PERSON` (`idPERSON`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_SOCIAL_MEDIA_PLATFORM1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`idPLATFORM`)
    REFERENCES `CarolinaAngeles`.`PLATFORM` (`idPLATFORM`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Después, al presionar next me sale esto. En mi base de datos en phpmyadmin me salen solo 6 tablas de las 9. Borré los visible y también las líneas index y también me tiraba errores.

```
Operation has completed with errors. Please see logs for details.

Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 3780: Referencing column 'idLEVEL' and referenced column 'idLEVEL' in foreign key constraint 'fk_SKILL_LEVEL1' are incompatible.
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `CarolinaAngeles`.`SKILL`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CarolinaAngeles`.`SKILL` (
          `idSKILL` BIGINT NOT NULL,
          `name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
          `isHard` TINYINT NOT NULL,
          `svg` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
          `idPERSON` BIGINT NOT NULL,
          `idLEVEL` BIGINT NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`idSKILL`),
          INDEX `fk_SKILL_PAGE1_idx` (`idPERSON` ASC) VISIBLE,
          INDEX `fk_SKILL_LEVEL1_idx` (`idLEVEL` ASC) VISIBLE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_SKILL_PAGE1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`idPERSON`)
            REFERENCES `CarolinaAngeles`.`PERSON` (`idPERSON`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_SKILL_LEVEL1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`idLEVEL`)
            REFERENCES `CarolinaAngeles`.`LEVEL` (`idLEVEL`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 11 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error lo tienes al crear las tablas `LEVEL` y `PLATFORM` cuyos índices deberías crear como `bigint` en vez de `int` para que todos los campos sean del mismo tipo:

```
idLEVEL bigINT NOT NULL
idPLATFORM bigINT NOT NULL
```

Una vez corregido este error, te permitirá crear las 9 tablas.